# Dimension of the span of a set of vectors with some coordinates set to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose

$$
\text{dim}(\langle x^{(1)}, \ldots, x^{(m)}\rangle) = r
$$

where each $x^{(i)}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ just denotes the span. (Clearly, $r \leq \min(n,m)$).

I'm trying to figure out what happens to the dimension of the spanning set when we 'zero out' some of the coordinates of the $x^{(i)}$'s. More precisely:

If $x^{(i)}_{ [i_1, \ldots, i_d] }$ is the vector $x^{(i)}$ with coordinates $i_1, \ldots, i_d$ replaced with zeros, e.g.

$
(x^{(i)}_{[1]})^T = (0, x^{(i)}_2, \ldots, x^{(i)}_n)
$

My question is:

> What is $\text{dim}(\langle x^{(1)}_{[I]}, \ldots, x^{(m)}_{[I]} \rangle)$ for arbitrary $I \subseteq$ {$1, 2, \ldots, n$}?

If we know what happens when $|I| = 1$, we're pretty much done.

Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here are some thoughts:

For convenience denote $d_I := \text{dim}(\langle x^{(1)}_{[I]}, \ldots, x^{(m)}_{[I]} \rangle)$

- If $I =  [1, \ldots, n]$, then $d_I  = 0$ as $x^{(i)}_{[I]} = \mathbb{0}_{n\times 1}$ for each $i$ (all the coordinates have been zeroed out).
- If  $I =  [1, \ldots, n-1]$, then $d_I\leq \min(1, r)$
- In general, (*I think*) $d_I\leq \min(n - |I|, r)$